# Segmentation fault in comparing the second byte of two files

Tags: c++, fread, fseek

I was testing the commands fread() and fseek, and I made a programme to compare the second byte of both the programme. The programme gave segmentation fault at the line indicated (the last fread()).

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *file1, *file2;
    long size1, size2;
    long size1a, size2a;
    char *name1, *name2;
    char *temp1, *temp2;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cout<<"Enter two file names"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    name1 = argv[1];
    name2 = argv[2];

    //open files
    file1 = fopen(name1, "r");
    file2 = fopen(name2, "r");

    //get file size
    fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
    size1 = ftell(file1);
    rewind(file1);

    fseek (file2,0,SEEK_END);
    size2 = ftell(file2);
    rewind(file2);

    fseek(file1,1,SEEK_SET);
    fseek(file2,1,SEEK_SET);
    cout<<"1"<<endl; //----cout worked
    fread(temp1,1,1,file1);
    cout<<"2"<<temp1<<endl; //---cout worked. 2nd byte of file1 was printed.
    fread(temp2,1,1,file2); //SEGMENTATION FAULT AT THIS LINE

    if(*temp1==*temp2)
        cout<<"same"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"different"<<endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Although I corrected the programme by defining

```
char temp1, temp2;
```

and writing

```
fread(&temp1,1,1,file1);
fread(&temp2,1,1,file2);
```

I still do not know what gave the seg fault at the second fread whereas the first one ran correctly. What might be the reason for the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) open files in binary mode `fp = fopen(name, "rb");

2) check the result of file openning `if(fp != NULL)`

3) allocate memory for data: `char *temp1;` is not enough, it is just pointer, you need something like:

```
  temp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * N); // N number of bytes
```

**EDIT:**

4) do not forget to close the file (even if it is not a cause of segmentation fault).

I just make changes and the following code works without problems:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *file1, *file2;
    long size1, size2;
    long size1a, size2a;
    long greater;
    char *name1, *name2;
    char *temp1, *temp2;
    // memory allocation (two lines added)
    temp1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    temp2 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cout<<"Enter two file names"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    name1 = argv[1];
    name2 = argv[2];

    //open files
    file1 = fopen(name1, "rb");
    if(file1 == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"File "<< name1 << " cannot be read" <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    file2 = fopen(name2, "rb");
    if(file2 == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"File "<< name2 << " cannot be read" <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    //get file size
    fseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END);
    size1 = ftell(file1);
    rewind(file1);

    fseek (file2,0,SEEK_END);
    size2 = ftell(file2);
    rewind(file2);

    if(size1>size2) greater = size1;
    else greater = size2;

    fseek(file1,1,SEEK_SET);
    fseek(file2,1,SEEK_SET);
    cout<<"1"<<endl; //----cout worked
    fread(temp1,1,1,file1);
    cout<<"2"<<temp1<<endl; //---cout worked. 2nd byte of file1 was printed.
    fread(temp2,1,1,file2); //SEGMENTATION FAULT AT THIS LINE

    if(*temp1==*temp2)
        cout<<"same"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"different"<<endl;    

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    // memory de-allocation (two lines added)
    free(temp1);
    free(temp2);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

5) de-allocate memory after usage (two more lines added)

Comment: "undefined behavior" is quite strange thing :-)

Comment: It worked, thanks!  But I still don't get it that in my earlier version, why did the first fread worked and the seond one did not! None of them should have worked.
Saw your comment later.. slow net! Thanks. :)

Comment: Perhaps, at other computer after compilation of other compiler the first fread  also lead to fault.... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: Maybe, the first wrong `fread` spoil something in the memory (prepare the error), and the second `fread` just manifest error

Comment: "The code works without problems"? You created a memory leak, and `malloc` should not be used in C++. And IIRC point 3 was an edit too, after you saw my answer...

Comment: @alain : why not, `malloc`, as well as `fopen`, `fclose`, and other C function can be used. Perhaps, I do not include `free` to de-allocate memory, but for this example it is not so critical.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first version is that the `temp` pointers don't point to anything:

```
char *temp1, *temp2;
...
fread(temp1,1,1,file1);
```

with this, the character from the file is placed at the random location the `temp` pointers point to.

With the second version, the characters are placed inside the `temp` variables, which is ok.

Comment: So why does the first fread work and the second one does not? (in the first version of the programme)

Comment: Difficult to say, it's a coincidence. Undefined behaviour is difficult to analyze.